# How to find out if deferred transaction was executed

Tags: deferred-transactions

In the [developer portal](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/communication-model) it says:

> Deferred actions get scheduled to run, at best, at a later time, at the producer's discretion. There is no guarantee that a deferred action will be executed.

How can I find out from within a smart contract if my deferred transaction was ever executed?

If it is "dropped" by a producer, will it still call the `onerror` action in my contract?

Comment: Might consider asking @tbfleming in https://t.me/joinchat/Esi1OkPktgcFeJ3Lmlcrqg | Related unanswered question: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/how-to-know-whether-a-deferred-transaction-has-been-executed-or-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todd Fleming answered this in the EOS Developers Telegram channel as follows:

**Todd Fleming**

> There isn't an intrinsic to do it. Flag seems like a good option.

Refering to [Gassa's answer about setting a flag](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/3293/118).

Me:

> Thanks. What if it's important to distinguish 1) dropped transactions and 2) transactions that executed but failed due to an assertion error?

**Todd Fleming**

> There's no reliable way. onerror is unreliable.
>   Deferred transactions aren't as useful as we hoped. Making useful guarantees on them conflicts with more important guarantees which won out.

Answer (score 2):

*I don't know about the proposed solution (the `onerror` part of the question). This answer deals differently with the original problem.*

At the very least, the original action can maintain a flag in the RAM, and the deferred one can clear that flag upon completion.
It might naturally be more than just a flag, depending on what you want it to do.

A practical example is `eosio.system` with its name bidding feature.
A bid event should return EOS to the previous bidder.
Instead of just sending EOS (which would be a vulnerability), it makes a record in the `refunds_table`, and then tries to send a deferred transaction with `bidrefund` action.
The `bidrefund` action transfers the EOS and clears the `refunds_table` entry.
In case the deferred transaction fails for any reason, the `bidrefund` action can be called again anytime, without the `eosio.system` contract's permission.
The code can be found [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/8b0d3fd/eosio.system/src/eosio.system.cpp#L178).

Comment: The fundamental problem is that there can be two cases why the flag was _not_ cleared:
1. The deferred transaction was dropped
2. The deferred transaction ran but raised an assertion error.

In my case, it's really important to be able to distinguish these two cases.

Imagine the same scenario of transferring funds. This works fine for a system contract with unlimited RAM, but it would make my contract vulnerable to a RAM pollution attack if I don't clear the flag upon errors. But I want to retry in the _dropped case_, whereas I can clear the flag in the second case.